# hibernate locking mode to lock multiple rows at once

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, hibernate, pessimistic-locking

How can I lock multiple rows at once in hibernate locking. Currently I am firing a select query to fetch multiple rows with an OR clause and locking the query with set lock mode for pessimistic lock mode. However in the hibernate logs I am seeing that the hibernate locks the rows individually with select for update.